# Excel - Creating 1 Pivot from 2 spreadsheets with different headings

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have spent quite sometime trying to get something to work, but not getting anywhere.

Scenario : 2 different spreadsheets, both with different headings, but the data is in the correct order and could just be copied from the one spreadsheet to the other and the pivot would work.

Below is the example of the 2 different spreadsheets :

[image: Spreadsheet 1 :]

[image: Spreadsheet 2 :]

As you can see, headings are different but the data could infact be copied and pasted and it would sort it out, but I can unfortunately not make any changes and this is why I need your help.

I have tried :

1. The consolidation feature, but that only works once off.
2. Setting the spreadsheets to tables and add to data model, but then I need to specify a primary key and join them with a unique field, which I dont have.
3. Ive tried using the Multiple Consolidated Sheets wizzard as well, but then it only provides "Column, Row, Value", but I need the actual headings to select from.

Ultimately I need the same result as if I would copy and paste the data from the one spreadsheet to the other, so I can populate the pivot.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: So let me understand, are you trying to combine the two tables into one so you can make a pivot table... is Contract # and Deal # related to each other?

Comment: Correct yes. Yes, Contract # and Deal # are related(Exactly the same thing in fact, but I can not change heading names)

Comment: Would there be duplicate (rows/data) if the two tables were combined?  Why can't you just copy and paste?  Is the data dynamic and connected to a data source that can't be modified?

Comment: Technically there should not be, but I would not like to completely rule it out. I can, but our client does not want to copy and paste...typical. Currently there is a pivot per worksheet, but the client wants them merged(The pivots). If I had to change the headings to be identical, would this be easier to accomplish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, I have found a solution myself.

I landed up writing some vba that grabbed both spreadsheets data and copied and pasted into a new sheet. I then linked a pivot to this new sheet. This VBA was linked to a shape(used as a button). The code is as follows :

```
Public Sub Combine_OpenFEC_ADM_and_FEC_GoldenPeanut()
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Consolidating FECs Peanut and FECs ADM for Pivot on FX Exposure Tab
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim Mainworkbook As Workbook
Dim wsFEC_GoldenPeanut As Worksheet, wsFEC_ADM As Worksheet, wsFEC_Combined As Worksheet, wsFX_Exposure As Worksheet

Set Mainworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsFEC_GoldenPeanut = Mainworkbook.Sheets("Open FECs Golden Peanut USD")
Set wsFEC_ADM = Mainworkbook.Sheets("Open FECs ADM Comm USD")
Set wsFEC_Combined = Mainworkbook.Sheets("Open FECs Golden Peanut & ADM")
Set wsFX_Exposure = Mainworkbook.Sheets("FX EXPOSURE")

'Clear sheet
wsFEC_Combined.Range("A1:Z10000").ClearContents

wsFEC_ADM.Select

'wsFEC_ADM.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
wsFEC_ADM.Range("A1:K" & wsFEC_ADM.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Select
Selection.Copy
wsFEC_Combined.Select
wsFEC_Combined.Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wsFEC_GoldenPeanut.Select
wsFEC_GoldenPeanut.Range("A2:K" & wsFEC_GoldenPeanut.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Select
Selection.Copy
wsFEC_Combined.Select
wsFEC_Combined.Cells(wsFEC_ADM.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wsFX_Exposure.Select
End Sub
```

I was hoping to not do it this way, as now the button needs to be clicked first to combine the data and pivot refreshed vs being linked to the existing sheets and pivots only need to be refreshed. Oh well...